# no funciona el AddEventListener

Tags: javascript

soy nueva en esto de la programación. Tengo el siguiente problema con mi código: debiese aparecer una alerta, informando la alternativa escogida cada vez que se cliquea alguna opcion, sin embargo, no funciona la alerta. cada vez que selecciono una respuesta no aparece nada. agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TRIVIA CULTURAL</title>
</head>
<script>
  function inicio (){
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // obtenemos los elementos con name = "diseñador"
    var elementos = document.getElementsByName("diseñador");
 
    // buscamos el seleccionado y lo mostramos por pantalla
    for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        if (elementos[i].checked) {
            alert("Has seleccionado: "+ elementos[i].value);
        }
    }
}, false);
  }
</script>

<body onload ="inicio"()>
<div>
  <form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <center>
    <h1>
    ¿Quién diseñó la cúpula de la catedral de Florencia?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="tiempocompleto"> Leonardo Da Vinci<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="mediodia"> Filippo Brunelleschi<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="sinempleo">Leon Battista Alberti<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="sinempleo">Miguel Angel Buonarroti
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como aclaración, `addEventListener` sí funciona... Tal vez sea el código, el que no funciona correctamente...

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que enves de usar **name** uses **id**.

En la funcion uses:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#diseñador').forEach(d=> {
  d.checked && alert("Has seleccionado: "+ d.value);
})
```

el **&&** es como si utilizadas un `if`

Usa esto y quita el ciclo.